# Polling with auto commit enabled in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, queue, kafka-consumer-api

When auto commit is enabled in Kafka and polling is triggered, is the (maximum present) offset committed before or after reading the new records?

Here we can assume that auto commit interval necessitate auto commit with this poll event.

Let me know, if question is not very clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On poll, if the auto-commit interval elapsed, the offset of the last message returned from the previous poll will be committed **before** getting new records. However, if that commit fails, the processing keeps going and the commit will be re-attempted later.

See previous question: [Kafka offset management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477567/kafka-offset-management?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)